# GitHub not adding additional Laravel PHP files to repository

Tags: php, git, laravel-4

I have a created a Laravel PHP application and now I want to push it to GitHub.  In the past I have not had problems pushing my projects.

However, I am having an issue with the current project I'm trying to push since only the default Laravel PHP framework files are being pushed instead of all the files within the project directory.  I am pushing this files via the command line.

Commands:

```
cd Desktop\Code\LaravelProject
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "First Commit" /* After I enter this command, I keep getting a 'nothing to commit' response  */
git remote add origin "My GitHUB remote Repository URL"
git remote -v /* Verifies my remote URL */
git push origin master
```

After I enter these commands, only the default Laravel PHP files are added to my GitHub repository (e.g. Creating a new Laravel PHP Project that contains the folders 'app', 'bootstrap' & 'public')

I have no idea why none of the additional files I've added to my project are being pushed to GitHub.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See your gitignore file

Comment: When you do `git status` do you see anything you want commited under "Untracked:"?

Comment: @Jack typing the 'git status' command gives me a response of 'nothing to commit, working directory clean'.  Also my '.gitignore' file only lists the following '/vendor composer.phar composer.lock .DS_Store'

Comment: Ok I successfully committed my Project files to GitHub but I had to do a few things differently.  Instead of using the Mac OSX Command Line Terminal, I downloaded the GitHub app for Mac.  Then I just copied my project files into another folder.  From that new folder, I pushed the project files onto my remote GitHub repository and now they are published fine.

Comment: I think what happened originally was when I initially created this Laravel PHP project, somehow the project folder created a repository and was 'synced' up with the default Laravel Homestead files that are already on gitHub, very weird.